# Find the volume of revolution formed by revolving the region bounded by the graph of y=1-x and the x-axis and the y axis revolved around the x-axis

Tags: calculus, volume, solid-of-revolution

Please Help, I'm in Calculus 2 and my professor didn't explain how to solve these type of questions

Comment: I don't know anything about such things but *perhaps* this can help you: https://www.rit.edu/studentaffairs/asc/sites/rit.edu.studentaffairs.asc/files/docs/services/resources/handouts/C8_VolumesbyIntegration_BP_9_22_14.pdf

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Problems/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx

Comment: Look of "volume [or solid, etc.] of revolution" in your textbook. This sort of problem is (inexplicably) ubiquitous in multivariable calculus classes.

Answer (score 1):

The [solid of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution) obtained in this way is a [cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone) with base a disc centred at the origin of radius 1 contained in the plane $x=0$ and with height the segment $[0,1]$ along the $x$ axis. It's volume is given by the formula:
$$\pi\int_0^1 f^2(x) dx=\pi\int_0^1 (1-x)^2 dx=\pi\int_1^0 t^2 d((1-t))=\pi\int_0^1 t^2 dt=\left[\frac{t^3}{3}\right]_0^1=\frac{\pi}{3}$$
The same result can be obtained in a more traditional way. In fact the volume of a cone is one third the product of the base area by the height size: $\frac{1}{3}\cdot (\pi 1^2) \cdot 1=\frac{\pi}{3}.$